# HP ALM Explorer - Module - Notification to developer

Tags: automation, hp-quality-center, application-lifecycle, hp-alm

Currently we are using HP ALM 11 at our company to keep track of defects and change requests! While logging a defect or change request we specify the module in which the defect was found or changes required. Is there a way to customize this tool so that we can assign developers to modules? And later on whenever the defect or change request has been made in specific module, each developers that belongs to that modules gets notified?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking to automate the HP QC, then you should have a look at two possibilities:
VX-API or the most recent REST-API.

Then it will be not so difficult to create automatically test/test-set/run/defect.
You can then assign a defect to a team or person and every time that the defect got modified/updated you can trigger a mail to the responsible people.

Unfortunately creating this kind of automation will require a bit of time and patience.

For instance I found ok a good start by using **requests** module in python and connecting to HP QC ALM REST api.

Full documentation is available on HP site and it's free :-)

Hope this help you a bit understanding your future tasks.
Have a nice day!